# Testing if a distribution over $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ is heavily supported on a subspace

Tags: coding-theory, property-testing

Let $P$ be a distribution over n-bitstrings which we will view as elements of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$. Given sample access to $P$, I am looking for an algorithm that tests if $P$ is heavily concentrated on a proper linear subspace $L$. That is, I want to test if there exists a subspace $L \subsetneq \mathbb{F}_2^n $ such that $P(L) = \sum_{x\in L} P(x) \geq 1-\epsilon$ for a given small $\epsilon$.

I guess a different formulation of my question is: I am looking for a tolerant tester for the property of $P$ being confined to some proper linear subspace $L$ of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$.

I know that for a non-tolerant test, corresponding to $\epsilon=0$ above, I can take $K=O(n)$ many samples $x_1, \dots, x_K$ and compute the rank of the matrix (over $\mathbb{F}_2$) formed by the samples in order to check if they span all of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ and this will test the property with high probability over the samples.

However, for a small constant $\epsilon$, this "rank-test" is not tolerant. To see this, consider that the test is taking $O(n)$ many samples, so there are $O(n)$ chances to land outside the subspace and so this "rank-test" will only be tolerant for $\epsilon = O(1/n)$. So, in some sense this test is too sensitive, however since I am working over $\mathbb{F}_2$, there seem to be no good relaxations of the rank function.

I would be happy for any ideas, pointers, related problems.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, constructing such a tester appears to be hard: at least as hard as the [learning parity with noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_learning) (LPN) problem.

Without loss of generality, we can focus on the problem of determining whether there is a rank-$n-1$ linear subspace $L$ such that $P$ is concentrated on $L$. (This is wlog because every linear subspace is contained within some rank-$n-1$ linear subspace.) This is equivalent to testing whether there exists $w$ such that $\Pr_{x \sim P}[w \cdot x = 0] \ge 1-\epsilon$.  That is the LPN problem.  I *think* LPN is believed to remain hard even if the noise $\epsilon$ is small though I am not absolutely certain about that.

In contrast, if you have ability not just to sample from $P$, but also ability to compute $P(x)$ for any $x$, then the problem can be solved in polynomial time by using the Goldreich-Levin algorithm to reconstruct such a $w$.

Comment: LPN also depends on the number of samples. Since we have as many samples as we want here, there might still be something which can be done

Comment: @CommandMaster, As far as I know, even with unlimited samples (well, polynomially many samples), LPN is believed/conjectured to not be solvable in polynomial time.  I *believe* this extends even to the case where the noise $\epsilon$ is small.  If there is something I'm missing, I'd love to learn about it!

Comment: Hi @D.W., thanks for your answer. I agree with what you wrote, so O(n/eps^2) should in principle be enough to test from a sample complexity point of view (just estimating subspace weight of all 2^n - 1 many (n-1)-dimensional subspaces?) but time complexity is probably an issue as you rightly point out.
About the connection to LPN, I have a small question. I thought that in LPN the input distribution is usually the uniform distribution over bitstrings which is not the case here, so I am wondering if this could help somehow.

Comment: @Marsl, Yes, good point, my answer is focusing on time complexity rather than sample complexity.  If it's hard for a special case (e.g., the uniform distribution), it's also hard for the general case (e.g., seeking a tester that works for all distributions), so I'm not seeing how it could help, but maybe you see something I'm missing.